# How do you determine the path of a particle placed in a vector field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, vector-fields

I have recently found a way of expressing newtonian gravity as a vector feild. First the Equation $$F=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$
I only want to know the accelleration in the equation since I only want to know the path the objects follow. So
$$F=-\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$
$$F=m_2a$$
$$m_2a=-\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$
$$a=-\frac{Gm_1}{r^2}$$

$a=-\frac{Gm_1}{r^2}$
states that the absolute distance squared away from the center of mass affects the force applied onto the object and not the angles $\theta, \phi$.
We can put this into a vector $$\vec{g}=\begin{bmatrix}
    -\dfrac{Gm_1}{r^2} \\
    0\\
    0
\end{bmatrix}_{spherical}$$
To transform it from polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates we can apply the Jacobian
$$J=\begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}  \\
    \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} \\
    \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial z} & \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} & \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial z} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

We are now left with this vector
$$
J\vec{g} = \begin{bmatrix}
    -\dfrac{Gm_1}{r^2} \\
    0\\
    0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}  \\
    \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} \\
    \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial z} & \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} & \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial z} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
J\vec{g} = -\dfrac{Gm_1}{r^2} 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    0\\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}  \\
    \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} \\
    \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial z} & \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} & \dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial z} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\vec{g}=-\dfrac{Gm_1}{r^2} \begin{bmatrix}
    \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}\\
    \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial y}\\
    \dfrac{\partial r}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}_{cartesian}
$$

We also know that $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ so this implies 
$$\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$
By the same logic this means that:
$$\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$
$$\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial z}=\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$$
Now we can plug them back into the cartesian vector field.

$$
\vec{g}=-\dfrac{Gm_1}{r^2} \begin{bmatrix}
    \ \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\\
    \ \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\\
    \ \dfrac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}
\end{bmatrix}_{cartesian}$$
Now plug in $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ into $r^2$

$$
\vec{g}=-\dfrac{Gm_1}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \begin{bmatrix}
    \ \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\\
    \ \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\\
    \ \dfrac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}
\end{bmatrix}_{cartesian}$$

pull out $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$

$$
\vec{g}=-\dfrac{Gm_1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} \begin{bmatrix}
    x\\
    y\\
    z
\end{bmatrix}_{cartesian}$$
The problem begins when I try to figure out the path followed by a particle evolving with time in the gravitational field with initial conditions $\vec{x}_0$, $\vec{v}_0$ and $\vec{a}_0$. I tried using calculus of variations to minimise the cross product of the vector field and $dr$ integrated from 0 to $\infty$, to get $\vec{r}(t)$ to be in the same direction as the vector field. It looked like this:

$$I =\int_C\textbf{F} \times d\vec{r}$$

But the function was required to be 0.

So please if anyone knows how to set up a differential equation to get the path $\vec{r}(t)$ set up with the initial conditions $\vec{x_0}$, $\vec{v_0}$ and $\vec{a_0}$ or even $\vec{\Delta a_0}$ that would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: $\vec{a_0}$ cannot he an initial condition. It is determined by the equations of motion.

Comment: Orbits under an inverse square central force are one of the most famous problems in classical physics, and were found hundreds of years ago. The orbits are conic sections. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem

Comment: Why do you think that cross product should be minimized?

Comment: @G.Smith the cross product should be 0 since I want my path parallel to the vector field

Comment: The Earth’s orbit around the Sun is not parallel to the Sun’s gravitational field. In fact, it is nearly perpendicular!

Comment: @G.Smith but that is the initial velocity that causes that. If the earth had no velocity then it would follow the sun's gravitational field.

Comment: That’s correct. But you said that you were interested in orbits with an initial velocity $\vec{v_0}$. Such orbits will not in general follow the gravitational field.

Comment: If the vector had a $\vec{v_0}t$ to give position added onto the gravitational field then it would take a path considering its velocity. In the Earth's case the path is circular.